# C code not displaying the correct thing

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a program with matrix. In four numbers, only the first less 1. When the first matrix finish, just the second matris less 1. And goes by to the end. The 0 number is not allowed.

For example, when I run the code, need to return this:

```
[2][1][3][3]
[1][1][3][3]
[1][3][3]
[3][3]
[2][3]
[1][3]
[3]
[2]
[1]
```

But that is not happening with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int fila[4], var;

    for (var=0;var<4;var++) {
        fila[var]=0;
        srand(rand());
        fila[var]=rand()%3+1;
        printf("[%d]",fila[var]);
        fila[0]=fila[0]-1;
    }
    system("pause>NULL");


    while(fila[0]>0)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d][%d][%d]\n",fila[0],fila[1],fila[2],fila[3]);
        fila[0]--;
        system("pause");
    }

    fila[1]=fila[1]-1;

    while(fila[1]>0)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d][%d]\n",fila[1],fila[2],fila[3]);
        fila[1]--;
        system("pause");
    }

    fila[2]=fila[2]-1;

    while(fila[2]>0)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d]\n",fila[2],fila[3]);
        fila[2]--;
        system("pause");
    }

    fila[3]=fila[3]-1;

    while(fila[3]>0)
    {
        printf("[%d]\n",fila[3]);
        fila[3]--;
        system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm missing?
Thanks.

That code prints:

```
[2][1][2][1]
[1][1]
```

Comment: Instead of using `system("pause")`, why not use a cross-platform solution like `fgetc(stdin)`?

Comment: Nice! But is not solving the problem

Comment: that's why I used a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Could you show what your code *is* printing?

Comment: `srand(rand())` is not effective; you should call `srand()` once, and not with the output of `rand()`.

Comment: Done. I think that it's screwed, but I don't find the stupid mistake.

Comment: I think that the `fila[1]=fila[1]-1;` lines between the loops are redundant, aren't they?

Comment: @user1178392 I don't even understand the description of your problem, Could you try to explain yourself better and grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two nested loops to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int fila[4], i, j;
    srand(rand());
    for (i=0;i != 4; i++) {
        fila[i]=rand()%3+1;
    }
    for (i=0 ; i != 4 ; fila[i]--, i += (fila[i] == 0)) {
        for (j = i ; j != 4 ; j++) {
            printf("[%d] ", fila[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The outer loop iterates until you get to the end of `fila`; inner loop prints the remaining elements of `fila` starting at the index of `i`.

Note that you shouldn't be re-seeding `srand` in a loop - you do it only once before the loop.

Here is the [link to this program on ideone](http://ideone.com/NG0NT).

Answer (score 0):

What you want looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[4];
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr[i] = (rand() % 3) + 1;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    while(arr[i]) {
      int j;
      for(j = i; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("[%d]", arr[j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
      arr[i]--;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Notice the nested loops. In particular, the inner for loop lets you print `j` entries of the matrix without having to copy/paste that code over again -- you get to eliminate lots of redundancy.